# how to upload image from localhost to server path in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting error 'Can't write image data to path', and i have folder permission too.

```
        $image  = $request->file('image');
        $name   = time()."_". $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $img    = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->save('http://test.server.com/upload/' .  $name);
```

Comment: Please check folder permission on server.

Comment: yes, folder permission already given.But, still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

first Install **intervention image** to your project

```
composer require intervention/image
```

after that
[image]

then inside your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

then inside your method to store file

```
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $fileName = $file->hashName();

        Image::make( $file->getRealPath() )->fit(70, 70)->save(public_path('path/to/dir/').$fileName)->destroy();

        $object->imageName = $fileName;
```

[this link](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) was taken as reference

Comment: also try giving 777 permission to your  **project/public/path/to/dir**